# elemMatch not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

I assume I have a model `MyModel` with 2 records:

```
{
  _id: .,
  rating: [
    {
     "name": "user1",
     "rate": 3
    }
  ]
},

{
  _id: .,
  rating: [
    {
     "name": "user2",
     "rate": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use `MyModel.find({rating: {$elemMatch: {"name": "user1"}}})` it returns no records.

I expect the call to return the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
MyModel.find({rating: {$elemMatch: {name: "user1"}}})
```